# How do i highlight the current selected date in a TextFormField Calendaring Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a calendar in my flutter app that updates a textEditingController when the user picks a date and this works fine but for example if i select yesterdays date and then go back into the calendar then todays date will be highlighted instead of the one i picked previously. How do i change this

The code:

```
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _date,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today_rounded),
            labelText: "Select Date"),
        onTap: () async {
          DateTime? pickeddate = await showDatePicker(
              context: context,
              initialDate: DateTime.now(),
              firstDate: DateTime(2000),
              lastDate: DateTime(2101));

          if (pickeddate != null) {
            setState(() {
              _date.text = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickeddate);
              currentDateSelected = _date.text;
              print('CurrentDateSelected: $currentDateSelected');
              // updateDate(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickeddate));
              _refreshSets();
              //print(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickeddate));
            });
          }
```